# Vim-like */# - (next/previous word at point) in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I switched from Vim to Emacs, and I am so crazy for Emacs now.

But there is a very, very useful trick in Vim and I can't use conveniently in Emacs, that's find next/previous word at point. Those are very handy with */# in Vim.

The simplest way is to move to the beginning of the word at point and then C-s and C-w, use C-s/C-r to find next/previous word.

Then I found another trick from [Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/), but still some minor bug.

Today I find a plugin - vimpulse which simulate vim in Emacs. And I can use */# there just like Vim!!
But seems the vimpulse will automatically enables Viper.

So, are there any other methods to implement this requirement? Or, Can I automatically disable Viper if I use vimpulse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First, the answer

Well, as is often the case, we can do better in Emacs.  The package I use for this is [highlight-symbols](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el)

Specifically, I bind a series of its commands with variations of the <kbd>F3</kbd> key:

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; highlight-symbol ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(require 'highlight-symbol)

(global-set-key [f3] 'highlight-symbol-next)
(global-set-key [(shift f3)] 'highlight-symbol-prev)
(global-set-key [(control f3)] 'highlight-symbol-at-point)
(global-set-key [(control meta f3)] 'highlight-symbol-query-replace)
```

Next/previous symbol is nice.  But I find it most helpful when reading an
algorithm to highlight a few key variables.

### On symbols vs words

The distinction between words and symbols is very nice for
programming.  I'm not sure if other editors offer this distinction.

### An alternative

Another related tool I find very useful for programming is [iedit](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit).

Here is how I load it:

```
(autoload 'iedit-mode "iedit")
(global-set-key [(control \;)] 'iedit-mode)
(define-key isearch-mode-map  [(control \;)] 'iedit-mode)
```

To do what you want, go to a symbol and press <kbd>C-;</kbd>, now
<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift tab</kbd> will move amongst matching symbols.

<kbd>C-'</kbd> (single-quote) will show you an adhoc `occur` view of the
buffer.

For a bonus refactoring tool, mark a region (maybe a class) where you want to
rename the symbol (variable), and press <kbd>C-;</kbd> again and only matches
within that region will be edited.

Comment: Awesome! I prefer highlight-symbol, it can highlight different symbols at the same time with different color. DO the same thing like mark.vim.
BTW, the colors is nice ;)  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Try Evil: https://gitorious.org/evil/pages/Home

*/# works nice with it.

Comment: It's awesome! How can I automatically switch to <E> state when open a buffer?